# formalizing the following format in Context Free Grammar / BNF?

Tags: regex, parsing, context-free-grammar, bnf

i have a file format that looks like the following:

fileformat : `<flag1><flag2><flag3><flag4><field1><field2><field3><field4>`

each flag is 1 bit, and each field is 1 byte. 
when the flag is '1', the respective field will be present. 
when the flag is '0', the respective field will be absent.

is there a way to represent that in EBNF/BNF without enumerating all the 2^4 possibilities?

Comment: If there were it wouldn't be context free.

Comment: Context-free grammars encoded in (E)BNF don't address how entities are packed, or deep semantic relationships among them.  It can encode the fact that you have 4 flags, followed by 4 optional fields, but not that the field presence is controlled by the flags.